# qemu and gdb error: could not load xml document

Tags: gdb, qemu

I'm trying to debug an application using Qemu for AARCH64

```
./qemu-arm64-static -g 1234 file.bin
```

When running GDB and connecting to the remote host, I get the following error message:

```
$ ./aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb 
GNU gdb (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1-4.8-2014.03 - Linaro GCC 2014.03) 7.6.1-2013.10
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-linaro>.
(gdb) file file.bin
Reading symbols from .bin...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
warning: while parsing target description (at line 1): Could not load XML document "arm-neon.xml"
warning: Could not load XML target description; ignoring
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

arm-neon.xml seems that it should be sent by qemu, strace of qemu:

```
read(4, "$qXfer:features:read:arm-neon.xm"..., 256) = 42
sendto(4, "+", 1, 0, NULL, 0)           = 1
sendto(4, "$E00#a5", 7, 0, NULL, 0)     = 7
recvfrom(4, "+", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)      = 1
```

Any idea what is causing the issue ? How is arm-neon.xml should be retrieved by qemu and how to solve it ?